# updating a column in a table having duplicate rows

Tags: sql

having problem updating a column in a table having duplicate rows..
I have a table "tab1" and its data looks like this..

```
Id   col2   col3     col4  col5    col6       col7  
1    xim       M     gtt   tif      1          2  
2    white     M     abc   png      0          25  
2    white     M     abc   jpeg     0          25  
3    gtc       V     ftt   gif      4          72
```

This table contains duplicate Id's but differ only in col5.
this table contains around 4000 rows
i'd like to update col5 such that the output looks like this..

```
Id   col2   col3     col4  col5     col6       col7  
1    xim       M     gtt   tif       1          2  
2    white     M     abc   png,jpeg  0          25  
3    gtc       V     ftt   gif       4          72
```

Is there a way to update this table using update statement, do i have to create a temp table for this update..??

Comment: How did you determine that it should be `png,jpeg` and not `jpeg,png`?

Comment: You are denormalizing your database. Don't do this.

Comment: Hmm swapping one bad design denormalised for another bad one multi value column. Id should be (4?) and if required another column added indicating a group, or better still normalising the design with another table.

Comment: @ruakh.. anything is fine, as long as the data is not lost

Comment: not only "," any delimiter would be fine like  "|" etc..

Comment: What are the maximum number of duplicates for a given record (e.g., will it always be just two, or could there be more (png,jpeg,tif))?

Comment: @JamesL.: it can go upto 5-6 but not more than 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments posted with by njk and Tony.  It's not a good idea to denormalize  your database, but perhaps your end goal is not so obvious and combining the image extensions is appropriate for your particular need.

This does what you are asking.  I'm sure there's a way to do it with XML too without using a cursor in a function...

```
use tempdb
go

create table tmp (
  id int, 
  col2 varchar(10), 
  col3 varchar(10), 
  col4 varchar(10), 
  col5 varchar(255), 
  col6 int, 
  col7 int
)
go

insert into tmp values
(1, 'xim', 'M', 'gtt', 'tif', 1, 2),
(2, 'white', 'M', 'abc', 'png', 0, 25),
(2, 'white', 'M', 'abc', 'jpeg', 0, 25),
(2, 'white', 'M', 'abc', 'gif', 0, 25),
(3, 'gtc', 'V', 'ftt', 'jpeg', 4, 72),
(3, 'gtc', 'V', 'ftt', 'tif', 4, 72),
(3, 'gtc', 'V', 'ftt', 'png', 4, 72),
(3, 'gtc', 'V', 'ftt', 'gif', 4, 72)
go

create function fnConcatCol5 (@id int) returns varchar(255) as
begin
  declare @rtn varchar(255) = '', @val varchar(10)

  declare cr cursor local for
    select col5 from tmp where id = @id

  open cr
  fetch next from cr into @val

  while @@fetch_status = 0
  begin
    set @rtn = @rtn + @val + ','
    fetch next from cr into @val
  end

  close cr
  deallocate cr

  set @rtn = left(@rtn, datalength(@rtn) - 1)

  return @rtn
end
go

-- it is more efficient to split up the 'distinct' and function call
-- into separate SQL statements so the function is only run *one* time
-- for each unique id

select distinct id, col2, col3, col4, col6, col7 
into #temp
from tmp

select id, col2, col3, col4, dbo.fnConcatCol5(id) as col5, col6, col7
from #temp
go

drop table tmp, #temp
go
drop function fnConcatCol5
go
```

The data returned looks like this:

```
id    col2    col3    col4    col5                col6    col7
----- ------- ------- ------- ------------------- ------- ----
1     xim     M       gtt     tif                 1       2
2     white   M       abc     png,jpeg,gif        0       25
3     gtc     V       ftt     jpeg,tif,png,gif    4       72
```